# Stick nav, but not at top

Tags: css, navbar, sticky

If I have this code: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/ObzgYo how can I make it so the nav bar doesn't stick right at the top but instead 20px below the top?

I tried to do this:

```
.main-nav-scrolled {
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  top: 20;  <== 
}
```

but that makes it stick at the bottom for some reason

Comment: `top: 20;` means very little unless you add a measurement declaration. Try `top: 20px;` -- without the declaration, there's no telling what the browser will use for measurements. It could be using 20 inches.. or ems... or centimeters..... making it move to the bottom.

Comment: thanks, that was the problem, why do you not need `px` when it is set to `0` but you need it for any other number?

Comment: 0 is 0.. .. 0 inches is the same as 0px is the same as 0cm is the same as 0mm... so using just 0 isn't a problem. But for any other measurement, you need to specify the units.

Answer (score 2):

The code you are editing is for both the header and the main-nav-scrolled class. Add a top value to the main-nav-scrolled class only and it works as expected.

```
header,
.main-nav-scrolled {
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  top: 0;
}
.main-nav-scrolled {
  top: 20px;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I find margin-x or padding-x to be more dependable.

```
.main-nav-scrolled {
    margin-top: 20px; 
}
```

Just note, in your example, margin will give you white space while padding will extend your background-color.